# Concrete 5 CMS index of Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, nginx

I would like to have the index page of concrete5 and magento 2 store. How do I configure nginx to use the index of concrete5 and not that of magento 2.
This site is multilanguage, use map to redirect in to the domain ITA/ENG/DE
[image: schema of magento]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go into nginx config and change the line `index index.php;'
To 'index ****.php;'

Please change ****.php to the file name of the concrete 5 index page

Once done 'Sudo service nginx restart'